# Python pandas bar graph with titles from column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data frame:

```
   year  tradevalueus    partner
0  1989         26065    Algeria
1  1989         12345    Albania
2  1991        178144  Argentina
3  1991         44384     Bhutan
4  1990       1756844   Bulgaria
5  1990      57088556    Myanmar
```

I want a bar graph by year on the x-axis for each trade partner with values. By this, with the above data, I want to have 3 years on the x-axis with 2 bar-graphs for each year with the tradevalueus variable and I want to name each of these by the partner column. I have checked  `df.plot.bar()` and other stackoverflow posts about bar graphs but they don't give the output I desire. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either pivot the table and plot:

```
df.pivot(index='year',columns='partner',values='tradevalueus').plot.bar()
```

Or use seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x='year', y='tradevalueus', hue='partner', data=df, dodge=True)
```

Output:

[image]